# Are Microsoft Emojis available as a library of SVG/images?

Tags: icon, resource-recommendations

I am a fan of [Microsoft's Emoji design](https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/), and would like to use them on my site without worrying about different devices/OS's using their own emoji set. This means using actual Emojis is not an option, and I will instead have to use images.

Does anyone know if they are available as a library of images? SVG sprite sheets would be ideal. My searches have come up empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You may check out [this GitRepo](https://github.com/notopsee/Microsoft-Segoe-UI-Emoji-SVG-Icons) which contains all Microsoft emoji as SVG and PNG:

## Microsoft Segoe UI Emoji SVGs Icons

[image: Emoji Banner]

3070 Vector based [Emoji-12.0](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-12.0/) icons out of the Windows 10 style from the
[Microsoft Windows 10 May 2019 Update](https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/windows-10-may-2019-update/).
The icons are available in SVG and high quality PNG.

The Windows 10 version has its own simple, succinct and even hilarious style.
It works great on light or dark themes. Unfortunately even on Windows it’s not possible to use it with every software.
Using them directly in vector graphics is very cumbersome and worst case: every platform displays it differently.
This repo should help to get a better access to this great font.

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for all this time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Free and Paid Emojis in SVG

You could use [these](https://www.flaticon.com/icon-packs/emoji) for free from **Flat Icon** or [these](https://www.emojione.com/emoji/v4) as paid versions from **Emoji One**, who apparently supply many of the biggest brands in the world.

---

For a complete list, but only in PNG, try [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/)

---

[image]
[image]

[image]